# custom will_paginate renderer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

[Documentation](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/Link-renderer) is lacking for will_paginate custom renderers:

> There is **no documentation** how to write your own link renderer, but the source code is pretty self-explanatory. Dive into it, and selectively override methods of the LinkRenderer to adjust them to your needs.

Is there any unofficial documentation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found a decent blog post about [custom will_paginate renderer](https://www.tachyonstemplates.com/2017/custom-renderer-will-paginate/)

```
module ApplicationHelper
  # change the default link renderer for will_paginate
  def will_paginate(collection_or_options = nil, options = {})
    if collection_or_options.is_a? Hash
      options, collection_or_options = collection_or_options, nil
    end
    unless options[:renderer]
      options = options.merge :renderer => MyCustomLinkRenderer
    end
    super *[collection_or_options, options].compact
  end
end
```

and then in an initializer

```
class MyCustomLinkRenderer < WillPaginate::ActionView::LinkRenderer do
  def container_attributes
    {class: "tc cf mv2"}
  end

  def page_number(page)
    if page == current_page
      tag(:span, page, class: 'b bg-dark-blue near-white ba b--near-black pa2')
    else
      link(page, page, class: 'link ba b--near-black near-black pa2', rel: rel_value(page))
    end
  end

  def gap
    text = @template.will_paginate_translate(:page_gap) { '&hellip;' }
    %(<span class="mr2">#{text}</span>)
  end

  def previous_page
    num = @collection.current_page > 1 && @collection.current_page - 1
    previous_or_next_page(num, @options[:previous_label], 'link ba near-black b--near-black pa2')
  end

  def next_page
    num = @collection.current_page < total_pages && @collection.current_page + 1
    previous_or_next_page(num, @options[:next_label], 'link ba near-black b--near-black pa2')
  end

  def previous_or_next_page(page, text, classname)
    if page
      link(text, page, :class => classname)
    else
      tag(:span, text, :class => classname + ' bg-dark-blue near-white')
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to previous answer, i wrote this code to use will_paginate with  [materialize](http://materializecss.com/pagination.html)

## application_controller.rb

```
 def custom_paginate_renderer
  # Return nice pagination for materialize
  Class.new(WillPaginate::ActionView::LinkRenderer) do
  def container_attributes
    {class: "pagination"}
  end

  def page_number(page)
    if page == current_page
      "<li class=\"cyan active\">"+link(page, page, rel: rel_value(page))+"</li>"
    else
      "<li class=\"waves-effect\">"+link(page, page, rel: rel_value(page))+"</li>"
    end
  end

  def previous_page
    num = @collection.current_page > 1 && @collection.current_page - 1
    previous_or_next_page(num, "<i class=\"material-icons\">chevron_left</i>")
  end

  def next_page
    num = @collection.current_page < total_pages && @collection.current_page + 1
    previous_or_next_page(num, "<i class=\"material-icons\">chevron_right</i>")
  end

  def previous_or_next_page(page, text)
    if page
      "<li class=\"waves-effect\">"+link(text, page)+"</li>"
    else
      "<li class=\"waves-effect\">"+text+"</li>"
    end
  end
  end
end
```

## your_controller.rb

```
# GET /articles/1
def articles
  @articles = @articles.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20).order(id: :desc)
  @custom_paginate_renderer = custom_paginate_renderer
end
```

## your_view.html.erb

```
<%= will_paginate @articles, renderer: @custom_paginate_renderer %>
```

Not the most  beautiful rails code, but it works

Comment: Thanks - I recommend upvoting the QUESTION to get more visibility on your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to the answers which have guided me to write this renderer for Bootstrap 5.

```
//config/initializers/bootstrap_paginate_renderer.rb

class BootstrapPaginateRenderer < WillPaginate::ActionView::LinkRenderer
  def container_attributes
    { class: 'pagination' }
  end

 def html_container(html)
    child = tag(:ul, html, container_attributes)
    tag(:nav, child)
  end

  def page_number(page)
    if page == current_page
      '<li class="page-item active">' + link(page, page, rel: rel_value(page),class: 'page-link') + '</li>'
    else
      '<li class="page-item">' + link(page, page, rel: rel_value(page),class: 'page-link') + '</li>'
    end
  end

  def previous_page
    num = @collection.current_page > 1 && @collection.current_page - 1
    previous_or_next_page(num, '<span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>')
  end

  def next_page
    num = @collection.current_page < total_pages && @collection.current_page + 1
    previous_or_next_page(num, '<span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>')
  end

  def previous_or_next_page(page, text)
    if page
      '<li class="page-item">' + link(text, page, class: 'page-link') + '</li>'
    else
      '<li class="page-item disabled">' + link(text, page, class: 'page-link') + '</li>'
    end
  end
end

//app/helpers/application_helper.rb

  def will_paginate(coll_or_options = nil, options = {})
    if coll_or_options.is_a? Hash
      options = coll_or_options
      coll_or_options = nil
    end
    unless options[:renderer]
      options = options.merge renderer: BootstrapPaginateRenderer
    end
    super *[coll_or_options, options].compact
  end
```

Comment: This is a flawless drop-in replacement and works great with Bootstrap 5. Thanks for sharing!!

Comment: Finally an answer that actually solves this issue with Bootstrap 5! Why is this not more popular?

Comment: I had to require the following at the top of the file:

`require 'will_paginate/view_helpers/link_renderer'`
`require 'will_paginate/view_helpers/action_view'`

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for a TailwindUI solution, I'm working on one right now using templates as the renderer.

Gist is [here](https://gist.github.com/alvincrespo/a5d3258cc899f3d39c129123b338733a).