# How to make numbers to be dots in will_paginate Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I'm using will_paginate gem.

I would like to show the recent six blogs on the landing page using three dots instead of numbers. (2 posts per a dot)

I've spent some time for the research but couldn't find any related.

Is there a simple way to approach?

**Update**

For the better explanation, I attached a screenshot

I want to display 6 posts on the landing pages with dots instead of numbers.

Three dots will be three containers.

Each container displays two posts and users can go next clicking the dots.

[image]

Comment: Kindly elaborate.

Comment: @Milind Hello, I updated my question!

Comment: This is not a Pagination issue but more of you setting up the containers and grouping them in proper structure.Check the details of the Carousel/Slider and look for examples.

Comment: Yes. It might be a possible way. I thought it would be simpler if I can just replace pagination numbers with dots. So I don't have to do extra codes.  I know this is possible using javascript slider feature.

Comment: No, its the slider carousel dots which is the number of slider items present.Either customize it or hide it.If you are using slick, check this out - https://codepen.io/tarkikRomanski/pen/MmZrzv

Comment: The answer is yes and [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44680975/custom-will-paginate-renderer) can help but there is no way to avoid writing extra code so I would recommend going with the carousel slider over custom will paginate but it is really up to you

Comment: Alright. I will just go stick to carousel slider.